# CodeIgniter only loading one model

Tags: codeigniter, model

As the title says, there seems to be a misconfiguration somewhere but I dont know where to find it.

My files are somewhat like this:

application/controllers/: news.php, people.php

application/models/: news_model.php, people_model.php

It's as simple as that, the news/news_model pair are working fine but when i use `$this->load->model('people_model');` in in the people.php controller, I get `HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request' error.

UPDATE:

It was an embarrassing bug. I forgot to add the trailing ?> at the end of news_model.php.  Thanks to all who answered.

Comment: The best way to debut this is to go into the people_model.php file and comments out everything and uncomment each line until the error comes back. The focus on that error and work it out.

Comment: `$this->load->model('people_model');` is exactly that part. I placed it in the constructor to no avail. I placed it in the method to no avail.  I have revisited this many many times, which leads me to think that it is a wrong configuration setting, but I have not touched config.php or anything like that.

Comment: This kind of error shouldn't happen with a wrong configuration. A HTTP 500 error is a web server error when requesting a page, and loading models doesn't use the web server to request the page.

Can you tell me what is in your constructor of people_model? Like does it try to include an external file? Have you tried loading just people_model and just news_model?

Comment: people_model.php
`<?php
class People extends CI_Controller {
 
 function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('people_model');
 }
 public function index(){
  
  $this->template->set('title','Faculty');
  $this->template->load('templates/base_template','people/faculty',$data);
 }
 public function faculty(){
  
  $data['faculty']=$this->news_model->showTables(); 
  $this->template->set('title','Faculty');
  $this->template->load('templates/base_template','people/faculty',$data);
 }
}
?>`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say to try to load the models on their own. people_model is an exact copy of news_model which is why this all seems so confusing.

Comment: I'm sadly on a deadline so im going to try and make it all work through my working news_model.  It isnt going to be pretty but well, until i can figure out whats going on i dont have much of a choice.

Comment: Please post the code inside your people_model.php file.

Comment: ok solved it... or rather, fixed an embarrassing bug.  I didnt close the php tag at the end of news_model.php.  Im guessing codeigniter loads the models in alphabetical order and every model loaded after news_model just didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

ok, glad to know you that your problem is solved.

you can avoid loading your model every-time inside Controller by using the autoload.php in config  folder.

```
$autoload['model'] = array('people_model');
```

though it's not the answer to your questing, but I think this will keep our code more clean.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: you can omit the `?>` at the end of the php file - it is not needed. And by not using it, you're safe from the pitfall of forgetting it.